# Binding property to a custom ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, itemtemplate

I have a ListView and a custom ItemTemplate (MyUserControl1).

```
<ListView Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="454" Margin="656,147,0,-461" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="337">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                <local:MyUserControl1 MyParagraph="{Binding paragraph}"></local:MyUserControl1>
                <TextBlock Text="test" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The MyUserControl1.cs only includes a property (MyParagraph):

```
public Paragraph MyParagraph
{
    get 
    { 
        return _MyParagraph; 
    }
    set 
    {
        _MyParagraph = value;
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

        for (int i = 0; i < _MyParagraph.Inlines.Count; i++)
        {
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(_MyParagraph.Inlines[i]);
            richTextBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Failed to assign to property 'App4.MyUserControl1.MyParagraph'.

I have migrated from Flex so I am doing something wrong but I have no idea where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to bind data, the target property must be a DependancyProperty, so in order to make this binding work, `MyParagraph` should be a dependancyproperty in your UserControl like below

```
 public Paragraph MyParagraph
  {
    get { return (Paragraph)this.GetValue(MyParagraphProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(MyParagraphProperty, value); } 
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MyParagraphProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyParagraph", typeof(Paragraph), typeof(UserControl1),new PropertyMetadata(null));
```